# Navbar image is not showing up

Tags: javascript, css, react-redux

I have a strange problem my image for my navbar is noy showing up and I do not know why. I have tried playing with different sizes and images but not nothing is showing only the alt message. Also it should be linked to the correct directory.  If anyone could take a look at the code and help I would be very happy.

````
The JSX
```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
 const Navbar = () => (
 <nav className="navbar">
 <h1 className="title">
  <NavLink className="logo" to="/">
    David's Bookstore
  </NavLink>
  </h1>
   <ul className="nav-links">
  <li>
    <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
      Books
    </NavLink>
   </li>
   <li>
    <NavLink to="/categories" className="nav-link">
      Categories
    </NavLink>
   </li>
   <img src="../images/user.png" alt="profile" className="img-user" />
   </ul>
   </nav>
    );

    export default Navbar;
     ```

      And the CSS
      ```
     .img-user {
      width: 50px;
      }

     * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
       }
     
     .nav-link {
     color: #121212 !important;
     font-size: 1.413rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     letter-spacing: 1.9px;
     }
   
      .body {
      margin: 0;
      }

     .navbar {
     height: 60px;
     top: 30px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
     gap: 50px;
      padding: 3rem 6rem;
      border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
      background-color: #f8f8f8;
       }

      .navbar a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 2rem;
     padding: 0 1rem;
       height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     }        

    .navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 20px;
    }

  .navbar li {
   font-size: 1.413rem;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: darkgray;
   }

  .logo {
   font-size: 2.875rem;
   font-weight: 900;
    color: #d51284;
    }

    ```
````

i have tried everything different sizes different icons but nothing is showing up.

Comment: I'm guessing the source of the images is not correctly linked since you just see the alt info. Unless you import the image in React, you need to point the source somewhere in the public folder. Let's say you have your image in the directory public/images/user.png in your app directory, you should set your image src to  /images/user.png. Make sure the image folder is in your public directory.

Comment: @JayF. ya I am using react and it correctly linked the image folder in the src directory but it doesnt show up

Comment: Hmmm... I would right-click on the image and inspect it to see if it shows 404 or missing in the console. If that is the case, the source is wrongly pointed. Do you see any other error in the console?

Comment: there is nothing strange in the console. I didnt know if I had to do something special in react... And thanks I will keep working on it

Comment: Try to remove the .. from the front of the link and use an absolute reference to see if it shows. Like if you have the image in folder /image/user.png.  and make sure you get the image if you go directly to the image link. Like http://localhost:3000/images/user.png

Comment: its in the correct place because when i added it as a background image directly in the navbar is showed up

Comment: but then it takes up the whole navbar...

Comment: I have recreated your code locally and it works fine as long as you have the image directory immediately inside your public folder. Checkout the links: https://ibb.co/YcfwxVW and https://ibb.co/8KG96Jw

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images folder is within the public directory, point the path to the images like this:

```
<img src="./images/user.png" alt="profile" className="img-user" />
```

(Don't use two .. just one .)